# Group actions and invariant subspaces

Tags: representation-theory, group-actions, invariant-subspace

Let $G:= S_3$ (So we have $\{e,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$

And it acts on some three dimensional vector space via permutation.

Let $U$ be the subspace $\{(a,b,c) \mid a+b+c=0\}$

I must show $\nexists W \subsetneq U$ s.t. $gW \subseteq W$ $\forall g \in S_3$, i.e., $U$ has no invariant subspace.

First can I think of $U$ as the span of $\{(-1,1,0),(0,1,-1)\}$

Then I must generalize to $S_n$ acting on an $n$ dimensional vector space.

Any hints or tips on how to go about this? I know the dimension of this subspace is one less than dimension of our vector space? Since we are putting one restriction on it? So dim $U$=$2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that $U$ has dimension $2$. The only proper (nontrivial) subspaces are then one-dimensional. Thus if such a subspace existed, it would be generated by some $v$. But then $gv = \lambda_g v$ for all $g$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: (This idea works pretty well for two-dimensional subspaces in general.)

Comment: Thanks! I need to sit snd work it out, what is $\lambda_g$?, makes sense though, the only subspaces that are nontrivial and proper need be dimension 1, say we have one called $W$, then $W = \langle v \rangle$? then we have $gv=\lambda_gv \notin W$?

Comment: It's a multplicative constant. I chose the letter $\lambda$ for very suggestive reasons.

Comment: ahh gotcha.. (eigen value reasons? lol)

Comment: Indeed those kind of reasons!